# Why does `pop` instruction NOT pop from stack?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, stack, segmentation-fault

I am doing a CTF-style exercise and I find something unusual in a `pop-ret`  gadget.
This is a 64-bits ELF file, the environment is Ubuntu 12.04.5(64-bit).
What I mean is like follows:

1. The instruction before SIGSEGV(`pop r15`)
   [image]
2. The instruction that come across `SIGSEGV`
   [image]

As, you can see, the rsp register did NOT change after `pop r15`(they are both 0x7fff90f83520)! The `pop r15` itself didn't throw any exceptions, but the following `ret` comes across a `SIGSEGV` as it is not a valid address.

Anyone has any idea why this would happen? I couldn't figure out why.
Thanks!
Tgn

Answer (score 0):

The pop instruction does **not** change the actual contents of memory. It simply copies the value pointed to by the stack pointer (which represents the top of the stack) to the target register (r15 in your case) and then increments **the stack pointer**, which represents removing the value from the current stack.

By the way, you didn't specify the instruction set, so I'm assuming it's something usual.

Comment: Sorry, I did not express it clearly. What I wanted to say is that the **rsp** register didn't increment either, I will modify my question soon.

Comment: It is a 64-bit ELF file, the style is x86-64. And I just find that the process seems to be dead when it is about to `ret` for unknown reasons.

Comment: It turns out that I have input the wrong gadget somewhere before, which killed the process. The instruction did not change anything because the process had been terminated.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I have input the wrong gadget somewhere before, which killed the process. The instruction did not change anything because the process had been terminated.